# How can I keep a material mat-drawer from closing when the user clicks off it?

Tags: angular-material, mat-drawer

Be default the drawer closes when you click off it but I only want it to close when the user click the cancel or save button in the drawer.

```html
   <mat-drawer #drawer mode="over" position="end" class="edit-drawer" disableClose="false" [opened]="false" closedStart="matDrawerClosedStart($event)">
        <app-vendor-edit *ngIf="selectedVendor" [vendor]="selectedVendor" (save)="saveVendor($event)"
            (cancel)="closeDrawer()" (delete)="deleteVendor($event)">
        </app-vendor-edit>
    </mat-drawer>
```

Comment: Isn't  the option `disableClose=true` the one that works?

Comment: You are right.   disableClose=true the one that works

Answer (score 0):

You are right. disableClose=true the one that works